# Is it right to use extension methods in my case?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, extension-methods

I use MVC4 and entity framework 5 in my project and I've lots of tables. As a rule of our project, we don't delete any records from database, each record has a isActive field and if that field is false, then we consider it deleted. I wanted to write an extension method to get active records and after some googling I wrote this:

```
public static IQueryable<Company> GetAll(this IQueryable<Company> source)
{
   return source.Where(p => p.isActive);
}
```

Now I can use my extension method to get only active records like

```
Context db = new Context();
db.Company.GetAll();
```

But let's say I've 50+ tables in my database, is it a good approach to write the same extension method for each of my tables. Is there a better way to write a only one GetAll() extension method for all of our tables? Actually I'm not even sure if is it right way to use extension methods for this instance?

Could somebody please help me and show me the right way? I appreciate if you help with code examples.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you are using Entity Framework, if you are depending on the normal generator (and I think you do), your case gets harder and I never had a similar case study. But, if you use normal POCO classes generator, you can use a base class let's call it `CEntity` which is a base class for each of your other classes (tables).

Are we there yet? No, to continue with this, I prefer to use the Repository Pattern, and you can make that repository generic (CEntity), for example:

```
public class Repository<CEntity> where CEntity : class
{
    public IQueryable<CEntity> GetAll()
    {
       return source.Where(p => p.isActive);
    }

}
```

And this is how to use it:

```
Repository<Company> com = new Repository<Company>();
Repository<Employee> emp = new Repository<Employee>();

var coms = com.GetAll();    // will get all ACTIVE companies
var emps = emp.GetAll();    // will get all ACTIVE employees
```

This is off the top of my head, if you had any other problems, put them as comments, glad to help.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer LordCover. I use database first approach. Is EF5.x DbContextGenerator a normal POCO class generator? If not where can I find a normal POCO class generator? By the way, in your example there is no definition for "source".

Comment: I know, `source` is just the Object Set which is the collection of objects.

Comment: But how do we say it has isActive field? Compiler gives an error like "no such field"? I guess I have to cast to Company class, but nothing will change, then I'll have to do it for all my tables??

Comment: Then you have to use Generics (Anonymous Type) and Reflection to get the field 'isActive` value from the object.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a point of interest, this is exactly how I implement my data layers, and i think its awesome :)

I also jam a repository in the middle as well but the general concept should work with or without.

Here's some working code examples of how I use this method in my blog for some similar use cases.

https://github.com/lukemcgregor/StaticVoid.Blog/blob/master/Blog/Data/Entities/Post/PostRepositoryExtensions.cs

I've found that it makes some pretty elegant code while still not restricting what you can do too much. Like i said, i think this method is awesome and really recommend its usage.

Comment: Thanks Luke for example project.There is oen thing I didn't understand(maybe more). Is database context class created for each repository or do repositories share one database context class(creates only one context)?

Comment: Yeah I suppose my example is a little more complex as i use a generic repository. Underneath there is one DbContext (https://github.com/lukemcgregor/StaticVoid.Blog/blob/master/Blog/Data/BlogContext.cs), however you can actually do the same extention method thing without using a repository if that works better for you by extenting IQueriable<YourType> or IDbSet<YourType>.